# How to solve this equation system?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$2x-2y+2=0 $

$-2x+2y-2=0 $

So, from the second one I get that $2 (-x+y)=2 $ which takes me to think that $-x+y=1 $

However, that's how far I get. How can I find an exact x or y value?

Comment: Those two equations are equivalent (they differ by a multiplicative factor of $-1$). Hence there is an infinite number of solutions: for every $x$, you can choose $y=x+1$.

Comment: Are you familiar with row operations and matrices?

Comment: Well, but then I can say that $2x-2 (x+1)+2=0 $ which gets me to the point where $2x-2x=0 $ and I can't find x's value. Or I can?

Comment: @Dave a little bit, yeah.

Comment: Well this system can be expressed as $\begin{pmatrix}2 & -2\\ -2 & 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2\\2\end{pmatrix}$. So performing some row operations (one operation really) shows that there is not a unique solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't: the first equation says the same thing as the second, so the relationship between x and y you got is as far as you can get.

Are you sure you got the right equations?

Comment: I think do... I'm actually trying to analyze relative maximum and minimum values for $(x-y)^2+1+2 (x-y)$ so I was trying to find where the gradient vector becomes 0, that is: $(2x-2y+2 ; -2x+2y-2) = (0;0)$ which took me to those equations.

Comment: @Anarelle That looks right ... So you don't have single point that is a minimum or maximum, but a whole line as described by your equation between x and y

Comment: I see now, thanks! And how would I know if it's a max or a min value (without having to plot the graph) in that case?

Comment: @Anarelle It is a mimimum, since once you fix $y$ (doesn't matter what you pick) you have a quadratic function, and so you can just look at the value in front of the $x^2$ ... Which in this case is 1 ... And if it is positive, then you are dealing with a minimum

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I follow. Why do you fix $y$ to get to that conclusion? (And it's definitely a minimum, after taking a look at the graph! I just need to prove it)

Comment: @Anarelle Well, maybe I don't have to fix the y, but I just know that any quadratic function $a*x^2 +b*x + c$ has a minimum when $a$ is positive, so relative to any given $y$, the function becomes exactly such a quadratic function.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your given system of equation has no singular - exact - $x$ or $y$ value. It does have a definable multitude of answers, however.

If we multiply both sides of the first equation by $-1$:

$$-(2x-2y+2)=-0$$

$$-2x+2y-2=0$$

by the Distributive Property. This is the second equation, so the first and second equations really mean the same thing.

As you have shown, $-x+y=1$. That means that we are looking for all solutions $(x,y)$ to that equation. With some simple manipulation we find that

$$-x+y=1$$

$$y=x+1$$

and so any pair $(x,y)$ where $y=x+1$ will work. For example,

$(x,y)=(4,5)$ and

$(x,y)=(5+\pi,6+\pi)$

are both perfectly valid solutions to the problem.

How you format this, however, depends on the given question.